# MySQL check whether current date time is between 2 fields date and time

Tags: mysql

In MySQL how we can check the current date and time is between the 2 fields which are stored with the start date time and end date time, i have tried like below, but it doesn't return any record and the code is below

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_user_rig_rentals 
WHERE (NOW( ) BETWEEN amount_paid_date AND mining_end_date)
```

where `amount_paid_date` is `2014-07-09 12:53:26` and `mining_end_date` is `2014-07-09 03:30:26`

Comment: What is return by `SELECT NOW( )` put in question.

Comment: Are both fields date fields?

Comment: @VMai Show the correction in an answer.

Comment: I think `2014-07-09 16:26:43` equvivalent `2014-07-09 04:26:43` so does not satisfied condition

Comment: Yes both are `datetime`

Comment: ok in case the `mining_end_date` is greater than current time,?? if we check with the greater than current time also not working

Comment: now amount_paid_date  is `2014-07-09 16:53:26` and mining_end_date  is `2014-07-09 20:30:26`, the query doesn't make any sense

Comment: @JothiKannan add for debugging the current time to your statement, i.e. `SELECT NOW() as mytime, * FROM tbl_user_rig_rentals 
WHERE (NOW( ) BETWEEN amount_paid_date AND mining_end_date);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you check you will check morning time with evening time where

```
amount_paid_date is 2014-07-09 12:53:26  <-- This is morning time
```

and

```
mining_end_date is 2014-07-09 16:40:26  <-- Change here and check it with evening time


SELECT * 
FROM tbl_user_rig_rentals 
WHERE (NOW( ) BETWEEN amount_paid_date AND mining_end_date)
```

Comment: @JothiKannan change `mining_end_date` value as i mentioned temporary and check what happen?

Comment: now it is working so the problem is about the morning time and evening time, how can can achieve the result the time is however ??

Comment: Now what you want to do just tell me?

Comment: i want to check whether the current datetime is between those fields datetime

Comment: @JothiKannan I think you better ask a new question with an exact explanation of your problem. You said in an answer to Jens, that you use both columns use the `DATETIME` datatype. Values in this column are indepedent of the representation. One problem could be that your insert into those columns is not right.

Comment: Yes @VMai is right jothiKannan ask as new question with proper explaination

Answer (score 2):

You get no results because the lower limit

```
amount_paid_date (2014-07-09 12:53:26)
```

is greater than the upper limit

```
mining_end_date (2014-07-09 03:30:26)
```

There's no value that can satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` isn't as smart as its name makes it sound, unfortunately.

`a BETWEEN b AND c` means this:

```
 a >= b AND a <= c
```

Unless `c` is greater than or equal to `b`, `BETWEEN` can never come up true.